# How to connect from the edge of a circle instead of the center

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, geometry

[image: here im added the link from circle center to circle center but i want to connect from circle edge to edge]

**Here im added the link  from  circle center to circle center but i want to connect from circle edge to edge**

*I want to connect the links from node edge to edge but im getting node center to center
is i did mistake in my code please help me out if any one know answer for this problem*

> here is my full working code

```
const VocabularyGraphh = () => {
  const svgRef = useRef(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3.select(svgRef.current),
      diameter = +svg.attr("width"),
      g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(2,2)"),
      format = d3.format(",d");

    const links = [
      { source: "animate1", target: "animate4" },
      { source: "animate6", target: "animate9" },
      //   { source: "animate9", target: "animate6" },
      { source: "animate3", target: "animate2" },
      { source: "animate1", target: "animate8" },
      { source: "animate3", target: "animate5" },
      //   { source: "analytics1", target: "analytics2" },
    ];

    let root = {
      children: [
        {
          name: "analytics1",
          children: [
            {
              name: "animate1",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate2",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate3",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate33",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate23",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate32",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate11",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate22",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate34",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate16",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate20",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate3",
              size: 1500,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "analytics2",
          children: [
            {
              name: "animate4",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate5",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate6",
              size: 1500,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          name: "analytics3",
          children: [
            {
              name: "animate7",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate8",
              size: 1500,
            },
            {
              name: "animate9",
              size: 1500,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };

    // svg
    //   .append("svg:defs")
    //   .append("svg:marker")
    //   .attr("id", "arrow")
    //   .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
    //   .attr("refX", 10)
    //   .attr("refY", 5)
    //   .attr("markerUnits", "strokeWidth")
    //   .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    //   .attr("markerHeight", 3)
    //   .attr("orient", "auto")
    //   .append("svg:path")
    //   .style("stroke", "none")
    //   .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");

    const pack = d3
      .pack()
      .size([diameter / 2, diameter / 2])
      .padding(100);

    root = d3
      .hierarchy(root)
      .sum(function (d) {
        return d.size;
      })
      .sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.value - a.value;
      });

    const node = g
      .selectAll(".node")
      .data(pack(root).descendants())
      .enter()
      .filter(function (d) {
        return !!d.data.name;
      })
      .append("g")
      .attr("id", function (d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })
      .attr("class", function (d) {
        return d.children ? "node" : "leaf node";
      })
      .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });

    node.append("title").text(function (d) {
      return d.data.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
    });

    const arrow = svg.selectAll("path.arrow").data(links, JSON.stringify);
    arrow
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "arrow")
      .attr("x1", function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        let translate = getTranslate(d.source);
        console.log(translate);
        return translate[0];
      })
      .attr("x2", function (d) {
        let translate = getTranslate(d.target);
        return translate[0];
      })
      .attr("y1", function (d) {
        let translate = getTranslate(d.source);
        return translate[1];
      })
      .attr("y2", function (d) {
        let translate = getTranslate(d.target);
        return translate[1];
      })
      .attr("d", function (d) {
        // console.log(d);
        let source = getTranslate(d.source),
          target = getTranslate(d.target),
          x1 = source[0],
          x2 = target[0],
          y1 = source[1],
          y2 = target[1];
        console.log(source);
        console.log(target);
        // let dx = x1 - x2,
        //   dy = y1 - y2,
        //   dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        return (
          "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + "A" + 0 + "," + 0 + " 0 0,1 " + x2 + "," + y2
        );
      })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)")
      .attr("class", "hidden-arrow ");
    //   .attr("stroke-width", 1);

    node
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", function (d) {
        console.log(d);
        return d.r;
      })
      .attr("class", "pink");

    node.filter(function (d) {
      return !d.children;
    });
    //   .append("text")
    //   .attr("dy", "0.3em")
    //   .text(function (d) {
    //     return d.data.name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
    //   });

    function getTranslate(datum) {
      const circle = d3.select("#" + datum);
      const string = circle.attr("transform");
      const translate = string
        .substring(string.indexOf("(") + 1, string.indexOf(")"))
        .split(",");
      return translate;
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <svg ref={svgRef} width="960" height="960"></svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VocabularyGraphh;
```

**if anyone give this solution thats so appreciatable**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `connectLine` to calculate the path between two circles:

```js
const connectLine = (x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2) => {
  const distance = Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);

  const prop1 = r1 / distance;
  const cx1 = x2 * prop1 + x1 * (1 - prop1);
  const cy1 = y2 * prop1 + y1 * (1 - prop1);

  const prop2 = r2 / distance;
  const cx2 = x1 * prop2 + x2 * (1 - prop2);
  const cy2 = y1 * prop2 + y2 * (1 - prop2);
  
  return `M ${cx1},${cy1} L ${cx2},${cy2}`;
};

const x1 = 30;
const y1 = 50;
const r1 = 20;
const x2 = 140;
const y2 = 160;
const r2 = 30;

const svg = d3.select('svg');
svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', x1)
  .attr('cy', y1)
  .attr('r', r1)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'red')

svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', x2)
  .attr('cy', y2)
  .attr('r', r2)
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'blue')

svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', connectLine(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2))
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200"/>
```

Comment: really thanks for you answer i have another quetions can you please figure it out i have posted recently here is the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74344972/dots-are-not-placed-perfectly-according-to-the-data-in-line-chart-in-d3-js